# What is right configuration for Play 2.4 / Ebean / JPA / hibernate-entitymanager?

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to migrate a Play 2.3.10 project to version 2.4.4.
It is using currently:

- `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaCore, javaJdbc, javaJpa, javaEbean, javaWs, ...`
- `"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final"`

I updated the build definition:

- Removed `javaEbean` from libraryDependencies in `Build.scala`
- Added `.enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, PlayEnhancer)` to `Build.scala`
- Added `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")` to `plugins.sbt`
- Added `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")` to `plugins.sbt`
- `"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.9.Final"`

In the end, I got this exception at runtime on one entity:

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: models.A column: _ebean_intercept (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

My guess is that something is wrong with the byte code enhancement, but I have no clue how it works. There is nothing exceptional with the model class, except that I updated the base class from `play.db.ebean.Model` to `com.avaje.ebean.Model`. It also has a `@EmbeddedId` that use another model that has `@Embeddable`.

Comment: I managed to get it working by removing the playJpa dependency. Fortunately for me, the app isn't making much use of JPA.

Comment: I thought JPA and Ebean are two tools doing the same thing. Why use both?

Comment: @Kris JPA can be used as an abstraction layer on top of the actual ORM provider.  In this case, the project was using ebean through direct imports and `Ebean.createQuery(Model.class)`, not using `JPA.em()` that much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have hibernate-entitymanager? I am assuming you want to use Ebean. If that is the case here is how i have it working:

1. Make sure you have PlayEbean added to the enabled plugins, and add javaJPA [ for annotations only], and mysql connector to build.sbt as shown below

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaJpa,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
)
```

2. Enable sbt play ebean so that your models are enhanced. You dont't need to enable sbt-play-enhancer if you have sbt-play-ebean enabled.

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

3. Add the database configuration and models declaration to `application.conf`

**application.conf**

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]

db.default.driver=<database driver>
db.default.url=<database url>
db.default.username=<username>
db.default.password=<password>
```